# Use youtube-dl to download all the playlists of a channel

Tags: youtube-dl

I want to download all the playlists of a youtube channel using youtube-dl.
The following command downloads all the videos even with `--yes-playlist` option:

```bsh
youtube-dl --yes-playlist -f best -ciw -o "${outdir}/%(uploader)s/playlists/%(playlist)s/videos/%(playlist_index)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s" -v $channel_url
```

Answer (score 11):

I found the solution:

in order to download them as playlists, set the channel url to the playlist section of the channel, i.e.

**Correct**

```
channel_url="https://www.youtube.com/user/channelname/playlists"
```

**Incorrect**

```
channel_url="https://www.youtube.com/user/channelname/"
```